# Accessing routing table via SNMP

Tags: snmp, mib, openwrt

Which MIB do I need if I am trying to find the routing table of a Linksys WRT54G with openWRT installed on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be MIB II. The SNMP ObjectID (OID) is .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21 which translates to `ip.ipRouteTable`. (This works for me on Windows, so I see no reason why it should be different for your Linksys/openWRT system.)

Here is the hierarchy table for the routing table leaf:

```
1 - ISO assigned OIDs
1.3 - ISO Identified Organization 
1.3.6 - US Department of Defense 
1.3.6.1 - OID assignments from 1.3.6.1 - Internet 
1.3.6.1.2 - IETF Management 
1.3.6.1.2.1 - SNMP MIB-2 
1.3.6.1.2.1.4 - ip 
1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21 - ipRouteTable
```

Comment: i am not able to walk through the routing table, although i am able to walk through ipAddrEntry table